# checking for a specific state not working when using multiple states per model (aasm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, aasm

Below are the states defined in my `booking` model.

**1st state**

```
aasm :booking_state,namespace: :booking_state, skip_validation_on_save: true, :whiny_transitions => false do
    state :pending, initial: true
    state :some_other_states
end
```

**2nd state**

```
  aasm :payment_state,namespace: :payment_state, skip_validation_on_save: true, :whiny_transitions => false do
    state :pending, initial: true
    state :some_other_states
end
```

Now if I do `booking.aasm(:booking_state).current_state` it returns the proper `state` name.

But if I do `booking.aasm(:booking_state).pending?` it returns below `error` instead of boolean value.

```
`NoMethodError: undefined method `pending?' for #<AASM::InstanceBase:0x005611e58e4cf0>`
```

What could be the issue here? I know if I only use `one` `state` per model this works. But not working when using `multiple states` per model.

Comment: Call that returns a `state` uses `booking_state` variable, while the latter one uses a symbol `:booking_state`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @mudasobwa yes it is a typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: Master branch of `aasm` declares methods like [`"#{namespace}_#{state}?"`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/master/lib/aasm/base.rb#L101-L104) when the namespace is specified. That said, `booking.booking_state_pending?` should work.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes worked..Missing in docs I think..Please provide as an answer and I will accept. Thank you.

Comment: For ruby gems I personally never rely on docs, I always go read a code base :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master branch of aasm declares methods like [`"#{namespace}_#{state}?"`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/master/lib/aasm/base.rb#L101-L104) when the namespace is specified.

That said, `booking.booking_state_pending?` would work.

Comment: any idea on how to fetch all records with `pending state`?  like `booking.pending`

Comment: https://github.com/aasm/aasm#automatic-scopes :: `Booking.booking_state_pending`?

Comment: `boolean` response do work `booking.booking_state_pending?`. But if  just call  `Booking.booking_state_pending` will throw no method error.`NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_state_pending for #<Booking:0x007fad60175998>`

Comment: Just go with `where(state: :pending)`?